# How to format a string containing numbers and characters

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have the following string `"2017-2"` and I need to format it as `"2017-02"`.

```
var period = "2017-2";
var periodFormatted = String.Format("{0:0000-00}", period);
```

periodFormatted returns `"2017-2"`

What is the correct syntax to get the period formatted as `"2017-02"`?

Comment: Calling String.Format on a string is meaningless.The method's description is : `Converts the value of objects to strings based on the formats specified and inserts them into another string.`. What you have isn't a period, it's just a string that someone may or may not interpret as a period.

Comment: Why not use an instance of DateTime. if you load your period in there you can use `dateTimeInstance.ToString("your format")`(in your case yyyy-MM)

Comment: If you want to represent a *period*,  create your own type, eg a struct or tuple that contains the year and month. You could even use a DateTime and ignore the day part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string.Format` won't know (or care) that your string contains numbers so you cannot directly format like that. You could split up the string and parse the last part as a number though. For example:

```
var period = "2017-2";
var parts = period.Split('-');;
var periodFormatted = $"{parts[0]}-{int.Parse(parts[1]):D2}";
```

However, you should probably have the `period` value as a proper `DateTime` object (or a custom type representing the year and month values) in the first place, that would have made the formatting trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the input-`string` as `DateTime` and format it in a second step.

```
string period = "2017-2"; 
DateTime temp = DateTime.ParseExact(period, "yyyy-M", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
string result = temp.ToString("yyyy-MM");
```

Note: `M` defines the month without leading `0` and `MM` is always 2 digit month.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings